# R how to add very small numbers

Tags: r, numerical, operation

It's probably easy, but I'm stuck on this small thing.

In R, I've being doing operations with likelihood values. Because they are very small I use their log representation to do their multiplication and division. However I need to add some now... how can I do that?

Example:

a and b are very small numbers

I have only A and B which are

```
A = ln a
B = ln b
```

How to compute

```
a + b
```

EDIT: I'm sorry for the unclear question. The answer is already present in [Dealing with very small numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802592/dealing-with-very-small-numbers-in-r?rq=1)

There is a formula for the sum of numbers represented by their log

Comment: `log(0.001)+log(0.002)` -> `-13.12236`

Comment: @wolf_wue I did not understood your coment. I will edit the question for more clarification.

Comment: Now it's much clearer, maybe consider about the inverse function of the natural logarithm, `exp()`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right, but what I understood is that you want to compute

```
a+b
```

given that

```
A = ln a
B = ln b
```

holds.

To get `a` and `b` out of `A` and `B` you just need to apply the inverse function of the logarithm for an exponential basis, which is simply the expotential function:

```
a=exp(A)
b=exp(B)
```