# Convert character base scientific number into number and preserving the scientific notation in R

Tags: r

I have this value in character:

```
 val <- "1e-14105"
```

What I want to do is to convert them into numeric and preserve the scientific notation. So the result is simply `1e-14105` as number.

I tried this but failed:

```
> as.numeric(val)
[1] 0
> format(as.numeric(val), scientific=TRUE)
[1] "0e+00"
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a floating point issue and the degree of accuracy to which R is working. It *is* converting 1e-14105 to numeric, it's just then approximating it to zero. See [The R Inferno: Circle 1, Falling into the Floating Point Trap](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/).

```
> as.numeric("1e-14105")
[1] 0
> class(as.numeric("1e-14105"))
[1] "numeric"
> 1e-14105
[1] 0
```

Comment: So there's no way to keep `1e-14105` as it is in numeric scientific format?

Comment: @qqq - maybe consider some of the packages for dealing with very small/very large numbers mentioned in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802592/dealing-with-very-small-numbers-in-r