# How to express extreme low numbers

Tags: r, precision, multiprecision

How can we correctly calculate the following?

```
df <- data.frame(logp=c(-2,-200,-600))
10^(df$logp)
# [1]  1e-02 1e-200  0e+00
```

This will give us `0` in `logp=-600`.  Can we handle this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could calculate it on the log scale (`log(10)* df$logp`) or use a high precision library (`10^Rmpfr::mpfr(df$logp, 120`) -- depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: The function `.Machine` provides a list of numerical characteristics and the smallest non-zero normalized floating-point number ~1E-308

Comment: ?duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802592/dealing-with-very-small-numbers-in-r