# compute probabilities from log scores

Tags: r, rounding, precision, probability

I'm using R and have the following task. Let's say I have access to `log(a)` and `log(b)`, and I want to compute `a/(a+b)`. Further suppose that `log(a)` and `log(b)` are very negative, e.g. -1000, then how do I compute `a/(a+b)` in the most numerically efficient way? Keep in mind that due to underflow, `exp(log(a))` will output a 0.

How should I do this in R?

Consider the following test case:

```
log_a = log(2e-100)
log_b = log(4e-100)
```

I want a function which can take these as log scores and output `0.33`.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802592/dealing-with-very-small-numbers-in-r) answers the question, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The following functions are transcripts of the code in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803470/8245406) by user [Joris Meys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428790/joris-meys), hence the name of function `joris`.

```r
naive <- function(lx, ly) {
  ex <- exp(lx)
  ey <- exp(ly)
  ex/(ex + ey)
}

logxpy <- function(lx, ly) {
  max(lx, ly) + log1p(exp(-abs(lx - ly)))
}
joris <- function(lx, ly) {
  exp(lx - logxpy(lx, ly))
}

log_a <- log(2e-100)
log_b <- log(4e-100)
log_x <- -1000
log_y <- -1001

naive(log_a, log_b)
#> [1] 0.3333333
joris(log_a, log_b)
#> [1] 0.3333333

naive(log_x, log_y)
#> [1] NaN
joris(log_x, log_y)
#> [1] 0.7310586
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>